# How to access the endpoint assembled inside an ear file?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, ear

I am building a web app using java ee as backend and angular as frontend. As application server i have chosen Wildfly 13. As a build tool for backend I have chosen Maven. I have created this structure for the project :

```
-Project
---Project-ear
---Project-model
---Project-service
---Project-service-api
```

Neither of this modules packages a war file, I package 3 jars and in the end I assemble them in an ear file using

> "Project-ear"

I have tried to consume the exposed service inside

> "Project-service"

but I cant. It seems I don't set the right url. Can somebody help me please?

I have tried to access the following urls:

```
http://localhost:8080/Project-ear/Project-service/resources/test/testDtos/,
http://localhost:8080/resources/test/testDtos/
```

I have created the RestActivator class :

```
@ApplicationPath("/resources")
public class RestActivator extends Application {

}
```

And I have created a Resource class :

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/testDtos")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getWorkflowDiagram() {
        TestDto testDto =  new TestDto();
        testDto.setFirstName("Test");
        testDto.setLastName("Test");
        return Response.ok(testDto).build();
    }
}
```

I don't get any error message, I just can't access the URL endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the Application Server (Wildfly) and add the ear artifact, it creates a target folder in your ear-folder. There you can find a file called application.xml. You have to set the context-root like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
  version="7">

  <module>
      <web>
          <web-uri>test.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>/api</context-root>
      </web>
  </module>

</application>
```

Your URL depends on what you have set in context-root in application.xml and how have set the application path in your root class (RestActivator).
In this example:

```
localhost:8080/api/resources
```

And to get access to your method in TestResource:

```
localhost:8080/api/resources/test/testDtos
```

Comment: Yes but this file is created derived from packaging into an ear. And if i change it manually, then when cleaning and building it will be removed. And i also dont have any war file